# Successfully codesigned and notarized app getting unable to verify developer when running

Tags: macos, code-signing, codesign, osx-gatekeeper

I have a fully codesigned `.app` which is successfully notarized. However when running the app on someones computer. They get the error

> "App" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

When running `spctl -avv App.app` it returns

```
App.app: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: **
```

And running `codesign -vv --deep-verify App.app` it returns

```
App.app: valid on disk
App.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Is there anything I am missing or can run that could expose what's wrong with my signed app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I have a framework in the `.app` that I codesign. Gatekeeper doesn't show anything wrong when I notarize it. However, when I didn't code sign the included framework, and then submitted to notarize, it came back with errors.

I simply codesigned what the errors were, instead of everything and that fixed the issue. Now the app runs fine on other devices!

Comment: What does "I simply codesigned what the errors were, instead of everything" mean?

Comment: What was the solution ?

Comment: @Derek, please explain what that means.

Comment: he means he ran the `notarytool log` with the request UUID and then he solved each one of the errors in the log.